# While inspecting Ionic app in chrome dev tools, how can I write JS in console to get page to scroll up?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I have an react/ionic app I'm working on.

On this one page, I have a single page app section. It has multiple tabs on it. When you click tab, the new content shows, but it keeps the scrolled position from the previous page.

Even when I inspect the app in Ionic mode, in a web browser, and I type JS into the console, there's nothing typical I can do to force the page to scroll up. I've tried doing much of this code in a useEffect, but it won't work. So I'm trying to simplify things and writing JS directly directly into the console. I'm looking at elements in the DOM and trying to target them. I can grab the elements, but calling any of the following methods on them don't appear to work.

I've tried to scroll up using:

```
document.querySelector('ion-app').scroll(0,0)
document.querySelector('ion-app').scrollHeight = 0
document.querySelector('ion-page').scrollIntoView
document.getElementsByClassName('account-settings-container')[0].scroll(0,0)
document.getElementsByClassName('account-settings-container')[0].scrollTop(0,0);
```

If I can get this to work in browser, I think it would help me figure out the actual code change. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

UPDATE: Oddly, when I copy the exact DOM element like this, it then works.

```
document.querySelector("#root-app > ion-app > div:nth-child(4) > ion-router-outlet > div > ion-content > div > div").scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your third attempt will work, if you call it like a function.

```
document.querySelector('ion-page').scrollIntoView()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

OK sorry I don't have ion-page. I have ion-app actually. 

So then it should be: 

```document.querySelector('ion-app').scrollIntoView();```

This is giving me 'undefined'

Which is odd, because this returns the element I would expect. I just can't call scrollIntoView() on it
```document.querySelector('ion-app')```